# Issue with read_xlsx/write_xlsx in R

Tags: r, excel

I have a simple Excel file available for download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2sedme68j43mrn95bhylq/Test.xlsx?rlkey=j9o1ylxt94ny2eep43h5yzxbx&dl=0). The file contains two columns, but when I read the file and subsequently write it back to an .xlsx format, certain properties, especially the newline property in some rows, are lost.

Example Excel file:

[image]

I read the excel file using `read_xlsx` :

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
df <- read_xlsx("./Excel Files/Test.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

[image]

In the end if I write the xlsx:

```
write_xlsx(df,"Test2.xlsx")
```

Output of write xlsx:

[image]

Thank you for the help

Comment: Is that `writexl::write_xlsx`? Using `writexl::write_xlsx(readxl::read_xlsx("Test.xlsx"), "Test2.xlsx")`, when I open the resulting `Test2.xlsx`, there is a newline in cell `B3`.

Comment: Yes `writexl`. Can you show your example. I tried your code but didn't work for me

Comment: Sure, https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfgEi.png

Comment: For the record, I'm on linux, R-4.2.3, `readxl_1.4.2` and `writexl_1.4.2`.

Comment: I tried different read and write package like `xlsx` but still the same result

Comment: my package version  `readxl 1.4.3` and `writexl 1.4.2`

Comment: isn't this the same question as your earlier question Golem?

Comment: I tried to improve the previous question. By pointing where the problem really starts rather than the dput of dataframe in the previous question

Comment: if it's literally the exact same problem, then I'd delete one of the questions, probably the earlier one

Comment: @Mark Can't delete it

Comment: @Mark Can you close the old question and open this one up